# Way to extract data from lm-object before function is applied?

Tags: r, lm

let me directly dive into an example to show my problem:

```
 rm(list=ls())
 n <- 100
 df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(n), x1=rnorm(n), x2=rnorm(n) )
 fm <- lm(y ~ x1 + poly(x2, 2), data=df)
```

Now, I would like to have a look at the previously used data. This is almost available by using

```
 temp.data <- fm$model
```

However, `x2`will have been split up into `poly(x2,2)`, which will itself be a dataframe as it contains a value for `x2` and `x2^2`. Note that it may seem as if `x2` is contained here, but since the polynomal uses orthogonal components, `temp.data$x2` is not the same as `df$x2`. This can also be seen if you compare the variables visually after, say, the following: `new.dat <- cbind(df, fm$model)`.

Now, to some questions:

First, and most importantly, is there a way to retrieve `x2` from the lm-object in its original form. Or more generally, if some function `f` has been applied to some variable in the lm-formula, can the underlying variables be extracted from the lm-object (without doing case-specific math)? Note that I know I could retrieve the data by other means, but I wonder if I can extract it from the lm-object itself.

Second, on a more general note, since I did explicitly not ask for `model.matrix(fm)`, why do I get data that has been manipulated? What is the underlying philosophy behind that? Does anyone know?

Third, the command `head(new.dat)` shows me that `x2` has been split up in two components. What I see when I type `View(new.dat)` is, however, only one column. This strikes me as puzzling and mindboggling. How can two colums be represented as one, and why is there a difference between `head` and `View`? If anyone can explain, I would be highly indebted!

If these questions are too basic, please apologize. In this case, I would appreciate any pointers to relevant manuals where this is explained.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question, but this is difficult. `fm$model` is a weird data frame, of a type that would be hard for a user to construct, but which R sometimes generates internally. Check out the first few lines of `str(fm$model)`, which show you that it's a data frame whose third component is an object of class poly with dimensions (100,2) -- i.e. something like a matrix:

```
## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ y          : num  -0.5952 -1.9561 1.8467 -0.2782 -0.0278 ...
##  $ x1         : num  0.423 -1.539 -0.694 0.254 -0.13 ...
##  $ poly(x2, 2): poly [1:100, 1:2] 0.0606 -0.0872 0.0799 -0.1068 -0.0395 ...
```

**If** you're still working in the environment from which `lm` was called in the first place, and *if* `lm` was called using the `data` argument, you can use `eval(getCall(fm)$data)` to get the original data.  If things are being passed in and out of functions, or if someone used `lm` on independent objects in the environment, you're probably out of luck.  If you get in trouble you can try

```
eval(getCall(fm)$data,environment(formula(fm))
```

but things rapidly start getting harder.

I don't fully understand the logic of storing the processed model frame rather than the raw data, but I think it has to do with the construction of the `terms` object for the linear model -- each element in the stored model frame corresponds to an element of the `terms` object.  I don't really understand the distinction between factors -- which are post-processed by `model.matrix` into sets of columns of dummy variables -- and transformed data (e.g. `log(x)`) or special objects like polynomial or spline bases ...

Answer (score 3):

The question is, how badly you need it. If you look at the structure of `fm$model$poly` then at the end you will see something like this:

```
attr(,"coefs")
attr(,"coefs")$alpha
[1] 0.06738858 0.10887048

attr(,"coefs")$norm2
[1]   1.00000 100.00000  93.96666 155.01387
```

I suppose these coefficients could be used to restore your original data from poly. See the source code for `poly` function (either `page(poly)` or just type `poly` in the console) ... it looks like computing the polynomials might be reversible. But why bother doing it? I can think of two reasons: (1) you have lost the original data and the only way
to restore it is this; (2) you want to understand how R computes orthogonal polynomials.

> Second, on a more general note, since I did explicitly not ask for
>   model.matrix(fm), why do I get data that has been manipulated? What is
>   the underlying philosophy behind that? Does anyone know?

Do you mean, why is data saved with the `lm` object at all? Just in case, I suppose. You can easily switch it off:

```
fm <- lm(y ~ x1 + poly(x2, 2), data=df, model=FALSE)
```

Or why are the data "manipulated"? I.e., why is `poly(x2,2)`  saved with data instead of the original `x2`. My understanding is that you requested this yourself. The `poly(x2,x)` part is first evaluated and then passed to `lm`, so that `lm` doesn't even have original `x2`.

#### edit - to answer the comment below in a more convenient way

> For instance, using factor(f) for some additional factor variable does
>   not get translated into a data frame being stored in fm$model. Only
>   the actual variable f is being stored in fm$model, whereas in this
>   case with poly, some transformation is stored. This puzzles me.

I think you've missed something here and the behaviour is the same for both poly and model.

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=2:6, c=rnorm(5))
> fm <- lm(c~ a + factor(b), df)
> fm$model
           c a factor(b)
1  0.5397541 1         2
2  0.9108087 2         3
3  0.1819442 3         4
4 -0.9293893 4         5
5  0.1404305 5         6
> fm$model$factor
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
Levels: 2 3 4 5 6
Warning message:
In `$.data.frame`(fm$model, factor) : Name partially matched in data frame
```

You can see that fm$model has factor(b) instead of b, and fm$model$factor is indeed a factor, not the original integer variable. (The warning is because the name is actually `factor(b)` and I used `factor` to avoid typing something as ugly as fm$model$'factor(b)' (replace single quotes with backquotes).

Comment: The motivation is that I am trying to program a small function that takes an lm-object as argument and does some computations. It seems more memory-efficient and, quite frankly, more elegant to use the data already stored in the lm-object, which is why I tried this. R's behavior here puzzles me though. For instance, using ``factor(f)`` for some additional factor variable does not get translated into a data frame being stored in ``fm$model``. Only the actual variable ``f`` is being stored in ``fm$model``, whereas in this case with ``poly``, some transformation is stored. This puzzles me.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I don't get notified when someone edits his or her answer, so I missed it... Anyway, point taken! I just saw that the original data was there (in form of the levels of the factor), and I did indeed not notice that the data structure itself has changed. So, whenever a function is applied to a variable in a regression, `fm$model` stores the data after application of the function, so the original data is difficult to retrieve in an automatic fashion, I guess... Anyway, thanks for your answer! That was helpful indeed.

Comment: The remaining bit still puzzling is that `head(new.dat)` and `View(new.dat)` show different things. If you have any idea what might be going on there...

Comment: look at `str(new.dat)` -- you will see that this is not a simple data frame because one of its "columns" is actually a 2-dimensional object (class `poly` but actually a matrix with some extra attributes). It appears that RStudio is just not good at showing such data, head() is right and View() is wrong. Compare `df1 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=matrix(1:10, ncol=2))` with `df2 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=I(matrix(1:10, ncol=2)))` with  `str`, `View`, and `head` -- View(df2) is particularly strange and misleading.

Comment: Ah, so it is an RStudio-thing. Thanks, that I did not imagine. I thought some internal R things is going on...